# AWS Cognito authentication equivalent on google cloud platform - secure a web app using google id authentication

Tags: authentication

Is there anything similar to AWS Cognito authentication equivalent on google cloud platform?

Answer (score 2):

Cognito equivalent from Google, Authentication as a service, is [Google Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/) with SDKs for all major platforms, protocols and Identity Providers.

There is also [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth), a bit simplified but customizable, focused on app development productivity.

- Here is a [comparison between Google Identity Platform and Firebase Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/product-comparison).
- Here is a [short comparison between Firebase Authentication and AWS Cognito](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/mobile#authentication).

One of the example in differences between AWS and GCP is how build-in sign-in and sign-up web UI is offered:

- Amazon gives you UI you can configure at your User Pool console. It is ready to use, no code, but won't let you customize the front-end more than by [editing css classes and uploading a logo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html). AWS equivalent of Firebase BaaS is AWS Amplify.
- Google provides code [snippets](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-integrate-with-pre-built-interface) and opens source libraries to build the front-end with, like [pre-built authentication UI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web).

Answer (score 1):

[Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) seems to be the closest equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [Google IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap) (relying on the identity platform) looks like amazon Cognito.

Answer (score 0):

There is product called identity-platform in GCP catalogue that is close to Amazon Cognito but has lot of missing features and is limited to predefined user properties.